# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to plot a graph that will change based on selected inputs. Moreover, the data in the graph should be categorized by state. The dataset that I am using is `midwest` which is from `ggplot2`. For some reason, the color which should be based off of the state from the `midwest` dataset is not working. I get the error when I try to use `color = state` or `color = prof_poverty$state`. `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): colour`. There should be 5 different colors since there are 5 different states.

This is my code:

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

prof_poverty <- midwest %>%
    select(state, county, percprof, percadultpoverty, percpovertyknown, percbelowpoverty, percadultpoverty, percelderlypoverty, percchildbelowpovert)

ui <- fluidPage(
   pageWithSidebar(
       headerPanel('Poverty compared with number of professors'),
       sidebarPanel(
           selectInput('xcol', 'X variable', names(prof_poverty)[3:8]),
           selectInput('ycol', 'Y variable', names(prof_poverty)[3:8]),
           selected = names(prof_poverty)[[2]]
       ),
       mainPanel(
           plotOutput('poverty')
       )
   )
)
```

SERVER

```
# Define server that renders a map and a table
server <- function(input, output){
    # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
    selectedData <- reactive({
        prof_poverty[input$xcol, input$ycol]
    })

    output$poverty <- renderPlot ({
    ggplot(data = selectedData(), aes(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol)) +
        geom_point(aes(color = prof_poverty$state)) })
}
# sRun the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: in aes, you dont need `input$` just the `xcol` and `ycol`. probs not related to your issue, but might be causing problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the data used in the ggplot call to `prof_poverty` and using `aes_string` should work. (although there are more modern ways to deal with this)

The way you have subset the data in your reactive `selectedData` hasn't worked and the use of the full vector of states in the colour aesthetic is triggering the error.

Given the `renderPlot` function is reactive, you don't really need a reactive data object `selectedData` created before this anyway.

```
server <- function(input, output){

  output$poverty <- renderPlot ({
    ggplot(data = prof_poverty, aes_string(x = input$xcol, y = input$ycol)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = prof_poverty$state)) })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand it better now that you have answered it.